# How can I search the public post in Facebook? Which API can I use to filter the post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**How can I search the public post in Facebook? Which API can I use to filter the post?**

```
$q = "Facebook";    
$search = $fb->get('/search?q='.$q.'&type=user&limit=10');
$search = $search->getGraphEdge()->asArray();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($search);
echo "</pre>";`
```

I cant be able to use the post in type attribute. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since Graph API v2.0, you can't search for public posts any longer, and this is well documented:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

> Public Post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)

In case you want to ask, no, there's no workaround.

Comment: Is any possible way to get the group information from search option?